# Parameter?_10 has no default member

Tags: vb.net

This is going to sound like a really silly question but it's been a long day.

I know I need to add DBnull.Value somewhere but for the life of me I can't figure out where.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Name", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Name", TextBox1.Text))`

Comment: Yes, I just need to know where to add the DBnull.Value so that the error will stop.

Comment: Did you try it?  The better way is probably like this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text`  It's common convention to use the @ symbol in front of the parameter name.  With that being said, OleDB ignores the name and just supplies the parameters in index order.

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value`